# It is optional to fill in a field

Tags: python, methods, odoo

How can I make it unnecessary to fill in the field `Evaluation_id` when I select the option `Class`?
Try to do the following method but it does not work for me.

```
class reserva (models.Model):

     _name='gimnasio.reserva'

     tipo_reserva=fields.Selection([('0','Clase'),('1','Evaluacion')])

     fecha_reserva=fields.Date()

     hora_inicio=fields.Datetime()

     hora_termino=fields.Datetime()

     estado_reserva=fields.Char()


     alumno_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='gimnasio.alumno', string='Alumno', required=True)

     clase_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='gimnasio.clase', string='Clase', required=True)

     evaluacion_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='gimnasio.evaluacion', string='Evaluacion', required=True)

     @api.constrains('tipo_reserva')

     def Check_tipo_reserva(self):

          if self.'Clase':

               raise 'evaluacion_id'=>required=False
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you want to do? I could just guess that you want to make `evaluacion_id`'s required state dependend on how `tipo_reserva` is set?

Comment: I have a drop-down button which contains inside "Class" and "Evaluation". there the person selects who wants to reserve the two. So when selecting the opcon class I want the option of having to fill in the columns where evaluation dependency exists and the same thing happens with the last, if I select the option "evaluation" I want it to only have the obligation to fill in the are necessary to reserve an evaluation because until today the program only gives me the option to choose any of the two options but it does not let me move forward without having to fill in all the fields.

Comment: Okay, now it is crystal clear ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `required` on field definition or set it to `False`. Your requirement can be solved by using view definitions:

```xml
<form>
    <field name="tipo_reserva" />
    <field name="evaluacion_id" attrs="{'required': [('tipo_reserva', '=', '1')]}" />
    <field name="clase_id" attrs="{'required': [('tipo_reserva', '=', '0')]}" />
</form>
```

Now the required state is dynamic and dependend on field `tipo_reserva`. That's only a short and ugly form definition, but i hope you get the idea behind it. You can also implement `invisible` and `readonly` within `attrs`.

Comment: If I want the spersonas can not choose the same time, how would it be? @api.constrains('hora_inicio')
     def _check_hora_inicio(self):
         if self.hora_inicio == False:
            raise ValidationError('Hora ocupada')

Comment: What is wrong with you @FranciscoGonzálezMejías this answer should solve the problem and you should not repeat your question two time.

Comment: @FranciscoGonzálezMejías That question doesn't belong into the comment section. Just write another question, please. And consider marking the answer as correct, if it is solving your problem. That's how StackOverflow is working.